# MATLAB fseek binary data read-in issue

Tags: matlab, binary, fseek

MATLAB 7.13.0.564 (R2011b), UBUNTU 12.04 (precise) 64-bit

I am trying to read in a subset (not starting from the beginning) of 2D data from a binary files. I know that 1 2D dataset is 5838952 Bytes:

```
>>whos

DATA               5747x127                 5838952  double
```

I try to use fseek to skip the first 400 2D datasets:

```
fseek(fid,5838952*400,'bof');
```

and then read in the next 100 datasets:

```
for i = 1:100
    DATA(i,:,:) = fread(fid,[5747 127],'int16');
end
```

But the code continues to read in the first 100 2D datasets without skipping the first 400 as I wanted. Anyone know why? Thank!

edit:

If I do

```
fseek(fid,5838952*400,'bof');
position = ftell(fid)
```

I get:

```
position =

     0
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of `fseek`? From the documentation:  returns 0 when the operation is successful. Otherwise, it returns -1.

Comment: fseek(fid,5838952*400,'bof')                                          ans = -1. I don't know why it's unsuccessful.

Comment: I've read that "whos" returns the number of bytes each variable occupies in the workspace so perhaps that doesn't match the actual binary file! fseek(fid,10,'bof')
position = ftell(fid) returns ans=0, position=10.

Comment: Yes exactly, see my answer. Your data in file is int16 (2 bytes) but double (8 bytes) in MATLAB memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeking off the end of the file. Run

```
ferror(fid)
```

immediately after

```
fseek(fid,5838952*400,'bof');
```

The data is int16 in the file but you are loading as double in MATLAB, so the size is four times as many bytes. You should seek to:

```
status = fseek(fid, 5747 * 127* 400 * 2, 'bof')
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great:                                                fseek(fid,5838952*400,'bof')
ferror(fid)                                                                                              ans =  -1
ans = Offset is bad - after end-of-file or last character written.                 status = fseek(fid, 5747 * 127* 400 * 2, 'bof')                                                                                                  status = 0                        
ans = '   '
position = 583895200